# Finding the volume of a solid of revolution when the function in question is an inverse trigonometric one

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals, solid-of-revolution

Here are two questions:

1. Find the volume of the solid of revolution, generated by rotating the region bounded by the graph of $y = \arcsin x$ and the lines $x = 1$ and $y = 0$ through 2$\pi$ radians about the y axis.
2. Find the volume of a solid that is obtained by rotating the curve $y = \arccos x$, $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$, through $2 \pi$ radians about the y-axis.

Now, I am new to integration but I decided to give this a go.

My method was as follows:

Question 1 - integrate $\pi(\sin y)^2$with respect to y and evaluate at the limits 0 and 1.

Using this method, I got an answer of $\frac12$ - $\frac14 4\sin(2)$. This is wrong, however.

I used the same method for Question 2 but again, got an answer different to the solutions given.

Would anyone be able to help me in order to determine the correct method for this problem and also such problems in general?

Comment: You have been around for six months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - let me just attempt to fix that. My sincere apologies.

Comment: I think that is better now :)

Comment: Did you see its graph? For the first question, the radius of revolution $r$ is $\sin(y) \leq r \leq 1$. If you take $0 \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ as an example, the volume is $ \int \pi(1 - \sin^2 y) dy$

Comment: @MathLover - I think the OP says that they are new to integration. I don't think he has understood your technique.

Comment: @vgupt were you able to see the graph of the region being rotated? Let me know what part you are struggling with. It will help me respond better.

Comment: Also to make sure I understood the region correctly, can you tell me if the integral I wrote gives the right answer?

Comment: @MathLover - I was not able to see the graph being rotated I don't think. In terms of what the answer should be  - the solution given for both questions is ($\pi^{2}$)/4

Comment: OK so seems like the region is between $0 \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. If you go to desmos.com, you can draw graph of $x = \sin y$ and see the region between $x = \sin y, x=1$ and $y=0$. That is the region being rotated around y-axis.

Comment: @Math Lover - I think I am starting to understand some things...however, is it possible you could please lay out all your working and explain each step in an answer please? I would truly appreciate it and it would help me to understand. thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working for the first one. I will leave for you to do the second one using similar approach.

[image]

The shaded region in the diagram is bound by the curve $y = \arcsin (x), y = 0$ and $x=1$. This shaded region is being revolved around y-axis and we need to find the volume of the solid of revolution. If we are applying washer method,

The lower and upper bound of radial distance from y-axis is $x = \sin y$ and $x = 1$. Bound of $y$ is between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So $V = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{\sin y}^1 2 \pi x \ dx \ dy = \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2y) \ dy = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$